# Excel: Copy data from another sheet based on time

Tags: excel, vba

If I provide date in cell "A1", then cells "B3:AA3" should auto fill.

**Sheet name: "AXISBANK-EQ"** : The sheet has the combined date and time in the first column which is imported from the software.

[image]

**Sheet name: "main"** : Based on the values in column A in main sheet, data should auto fill in corresponding rows i.e "B3 :AA3" in this example.

[image]

**To simplify when I give date in cell A1. The B3 cell should have the value of 439.5.**

I could not find the solution. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please update your post with any formula or vba code you have already tried highlighting specific issues you're facing.

Comment: @Super Symmetry I could not find the desired solution

Comment: Rather than using strings for time such as "09:15" use a formula that works out the whole date (including the time). Something like `=$A$1+TIME(8,45,0)+TIME(0,15,0)*COLUMN()`. To display just the time use a custom number format "hh:mm". Now you can use a lookup formula matching the stock name and the **full date**

Comment: @Super Symmetry Still a bit confusing. Would it be possible to give a working example?